# How to store few millions of cache and then track down 20 oldest cache

Tags: caching, data-structures, language-agnostic

I got an interview question saying I need to store few millions of cache and then I need to keep a track on 20 oldest cache and as soon as the threshold of cache collection increases, replace the 20 oldest with next set of oldest cache.

> I answered to keep a hashmap for it, again the question increases
>   what if we wanna access any of the element on hashmap fastly, how to
>   do, so I told its map so accessing won't be time taking but
>   interviewer was not satisfied. So what should be the idle way for such
>   scenarios.

Comment: Your interviewer seems to be describing an [LRU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) which does not appear to have any trivial implementations.  Should make for interesting studying...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) is well-suited to finding and removing the oldest members.

> A queue implemented as a doubly linked list has O(1) insertion and deletion at both ends.

A [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) lends itself to giving different weights to different items in the queue (e.g. some queue elements may be more expensive to re-create than others).

You can use a hash map to hold the actual elements and find them quickly based on the hash key, and a queue *of the hash keys* to track age of cache elements.

Comment: it means to keep a seperate queue which will keep the reference of 20 oldest item of Map ?, but is the store of millions records in Map is the efficient thing to do

Comment: No... have a queue holding a reference to all cache elements.  A map is very efficient at finding an element based on a hash key, but horribly inefficient for finding elements based on search criteria such as timestamp.  The queue could hold only the hash key... use the queue to enqueue and dequeue elements based on age, and use the hashmap to hold the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

By using a double-linked list for the queue and also maintaining a hash map of the elements you should be able to make a cache that supports a max size (or even a LRU cache). This should result in references to objects being stored 3 times and not the object being stored twice, be sure to check for this if you implement this (a simple way to avoid this is to just queue the hash key)

When checking for overflow you just pop the last item off the queue and then remove it from the hash map

When accessing an item you can use the hash map to find the cached item. Then if you are implementing a LRU cache you just remove it from the queue and add it back to the beginning, this.

By using this structure Insert, Update, Read, Delete are all going to be `O(1)`.

The follow on question to expect is for an interviewer to ask for the ability for items to have a time-to-live (TTL) that varies per cached item. For this you need to have another queue that maintains items ordered by time-to-live, the only problem here is that inserts now become `O(n)` as you have to scan the TTL queue and find the spot to expire, so you have to decide if the memory usage of storing the TTL queue as a n-tree will be worthwhile (thereby yielding `O(log n)` insert time). Or you could implement your TTL queue as buckets for each ~1minute interval or similar, you get ~`O(1)` inserts still and just degrade the performance of your expiration background process slightly but not greatly (and it's a background process).